# seg fault after trying to access ladder part of sbrk free space

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Ok, so I have a struct that looks like

```
typedef struct meta {
    size_t size;
    struct meta* next;
    struct meta* prev;
} meta_t;
```

I also statically allocate the beginning list pointer and the end list pointer as:

```
static meta_t* freelist_b = NULL;
static meta_t* freelist_e = NULL;
```

I then free a block of 4 MB of space and set the beginning list pointer to it

```
size_t max_bytes = ALIGN(1024*1024*4);
freelist_b = (meta_t*) sbrk(max_bytes);
```

Then I try to do the same for the end of list pointer

```
freelist_e = memcpy(freelist_b+max_bytes-sizeof(meta_t),freelist_b,sizeof(meta_t));
```

But this line gives a segmentation fault.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to further debug this?  Thanks.

Comment: "Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong" - surely the debugger can?

Comment: Where did this `freelist_p` variable come from? Could you please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Sorry, renamed it, it should have been freelist_b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `freelist_b+max_bytes-sizeof(meta_t)`, you are using `operator+` on a pointer to a `meta_t` structure. This adds a lot more than what you probably expect.

Change:

```
freelist_b
```

To:

```
(char*)freelist_b
```

Or change:

```
max_bytes-sizeof(meta_t)
```

To:

```
max_bytes/sizeof(meta_t)-1
```